# How do I import .nif files into blender 2.77?

Tags: add-on

There used to be an add-on in older versions but I do not see it in this new version.

Comment: Check this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51544/can-someone-make-a-plugin-for-nif-like-3ds-max-has

Comment: Short answer - you can't @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I wouldn't call this a duplicate, as that question was asking someone to make an addon, this one is merely asking if and how a certain import is possible.

Comment: There are two links in my answer there that point to two different nif import/export plugins

Comment: did you try to download an old version of blender that works with that addon, install the addon and import, save to blend or export to other format, then import that new file into current blender?